# If $x^2$ is divisible by $4$ then $x$ is even?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I am studying discrete mathematics as course and I have to prove this

> "If $x^2$ is divisible by $4$ then $x$ is even".

I am wondering  how to prove it using the contrapositive of this statement.

Please guide me on this proof approach.

Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: In fact, if $x^2$ is divisible by $2$ then $x$ is even!

Comment: If you want to ask a new question, please ask a new question instead of editing this one.

Comment: Hamxa: Is there a reason you just tried to vandalize my answer?

Comment: @amWhy: ... I'm thinking hacked account, confused user or ... dare I say it, a new type of internet creature.

Answer (score 4):

To prove a statement $p \rightarrow q$, we can instead prove its contrapositive $\lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p$, because the two forms of implication are equivalent: an implication is true if and only if its contrapositive is true: $$p\rightarrow q \equiv \lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p.$$

Let $p$ denote "$4$ divides $x^2$."

- $\lnot p: \;$ "$4$ does *not* divide $x^2$", or equivalently, "$x^2$ is *not* divisible by $4$."

Let $q$ denote "$x$ is even."

- $\lnot q:\;$ "$x$ is not even", or equivalently, "$x$ is odd."

We want to prove $p\rightarrow q$ by proving $\lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p$.

---

**Proof:**

Suppose $x$ is *not* even (that is, suppose $x$ is odd). Then $x = 2k+1$ for some integer $k$.

And if $x= 2k+1$, it follows that $$x^2 = (2k+1)^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1 = 4(k^2 + k) + 1$$

Clearly, $4$ does not divide $x^2 = 4(k^2+k) +1$, because  $4$ does not divide $1$.

Having proved "$x$ not even" $\implies$ "$x^2$ is not divisible by $4$," we have proved its equivalent:

> "If $x^2$ is divisible by 4, then $x$ must be even,"

as desired.

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ were odd, then $x=2k+1$ for some integer $k$, in which case $\,x^2=\;\ldots\;\;?$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

If not. Let $x=2k+1$. Then $x^2=(2k+1)^2=4k^2+4k+1$.